# What is area region type HUD and where to find?

Tags: python, 3d-view, interface

In Blender API (3.4) I can see that HUD is a Floating Region

> `Region Type Items >   HUD: Floating Region`
> [Region Type Items](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/region_type_items.html#region-type-items)

and attribute *show_region_hud* is available for some (not all) SpaceEditors.

> bpy.types.SpaceClipEditor.show_region_hud
> bpy.types.SpaceGraphEditor.show_region_hud
> bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.show_region_hud
> bpy.types.SpaceSequenceEditor.show_region_hud
> bpy.types.SpaceView3D.show_region_hud

[image]

But I can't notice any difference in UI when I toggle `VIEW3D.spaces[0].show_region_hud` in Workspace Layout. Attribute was changed. No context error.

```
import bpy
for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:                     
    if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
        print("VIEW3D Regions in [%s] " % bpy.context.workspace.name)
        for region in area.regions:     
            print("  -", region.type)
        print(area.spaces[0].show_region_hud)
        area.spaces[0].show_region_hud = not area.spaces[0].show_region_hud       
        print(area.spaces[0].show_region_hud)
        break
```

In Blender Manual there´s no hit for *region type HUD*.

Three matches on Blender SE, but not very helpful for me:

[Is there a reference for how to add custom keymaps to operators in an addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200811/is-there-a-reference-for-how-to-add-custom-keymaps-to-operators-in-an-addon/200812#200812)

[What is the purpose of shift-f](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72699/what-is-the-purpose-of-shift-f/72701#72701)

[Sub Panels for the Add Object template](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281775/sub-panels-for-the-add-object-template)

Does anyone knows more about?

Comment: AFAIK HUD is the popup panel that opens in the lower left of the 3D viewport when you use an operator

Comment: That's it. You are absolutely right. With `area.spaces[0].show_region_hud = False` there is no operator panel anymore. Please make an answer I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: @relaxed, just to add i think it is the same as "Adjust Last Operation" in the View menu of a 3D viewport

Comment: @R M K Close, but the setting can be used to prevent the operator from popping up in the lower left corner.

Comment: I think there is a setting specifically for that in `bl_options` of an operator. In my experience messing with this panel leads to undefined brehaviours (crash) see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/operator_type_flag_items.html#rna-enum-operator-type-flag-items